# Gradient on manifolds and level sets

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M^n$ be a smooth Riemannian $n$-manifold and $f\in C^{\infty}(M;\mathbb{R})$. Let $p\in M$ be such that $\operatorname{grad}_p f\neq 0$ and $f(p)=c$. I want to prove that $f^{-1}(c)$ defines a $(n-1)$-submanifold on a neighborhood of $p$. For this purpose, I'm trying to prove that $f$ is submersive at $f^{-1}(c)$, i.e., that $D_pf:T_pM\rightarrow T_c\mathbb{R}$ is onto. However, I'm having problems trying to prove this. I've tried directly and via factoring $f$ through a chart, but I got stucked in both tries.

Could you guys lend me hand? I'd really appreciate it!

Thank you!

Comment: What is the relationship between $D_pf$ and $\text{grad}_pf$?

Comment: We have the relation $\langle\operatorname{grad}_p f, v\rangle_p=d_pf(v), \forall v\in T_pM$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_p$ is the inner product in $T_pM$ induced by the Riemannian structure of $M$.

Comment: Ok, so if the gradient is non-zero, what can you say about $D_pf$? (recall the inner product is non-degenerate, meaning it gives an isomorphism between $T_pM$ and $T_p^*M$)

Comment: Maybe we can say that $D_p f$ it's not identically zero? If it were to be identically zero, then $\langle\operatorname{grad}_pf,v\rangle_p=0, \forall v\in T_pM$ and this implies that $\operatorname{grad}_p f =0$, right?

Comment: But how not being identically zero implies surjectivity?

Comment: The target space is one-dimensional

Comment: Ok. Now I get it. Sorry for my clumsiness. Thank you very much!!

Comment: It seems that the confusion is now solved, @JaviLark01 I suggest you to either right up an answer (which I will gladly upvote), or delete the post.